# Binding to properties of nested entities in web workflow designer

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a workflow defined on entity A as the primary entity. A is related to Entity B(1:1) which in turn is related to entity C(1:1)
In the web workflow designer's "Set properties" dialog I can bind to properties of B since it is directly related to B. Is it possible to bind to properties of C using the Form Assistant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short. No; unfortunately. In the workflow designer that you use within CRM, you can jump across to a related entities attributes ie Entity B in your example. However you can go no further.

If you need to do something with Entity C you will need to code a Workflow Assembly that takes the values you want as input parameters and then in the code programmatically update entity C.

[Msdn Article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309745.aspx)

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks for confirming.